# Issue using replaceWith() in each() on cloned set

Tags: jquery

The following code is split up and has been reduced to show that I'm having difficulties replacing one element with another.  In this case heading elements with list items.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var headingElements = $(':header').clone();
                var listElements =  $(headingElements).each(function(){
                    $(this).replaceWith($('<li></li>'));
                });
                //EDIT AFTER POSTED, FROM: 
                //$(".toc").append('<ul/>').appendTo(listElements);
                //TO
                $('<ul/>').append(listElements).appendTo(".toc");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="toc"></div>
        <h1>TOC</h1>
        <h1>one</h1>
        <h2>two</h2>
        <h3>three</h3>
        <h2>two</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Current Output

  ## TOC
  ## one
  ### two
  #### three
  ### two

## TOC

## one

### two

#### three

### two

What I expected

- 
- 
- 
- 
- 

## TOC

## one

### two

#### three

### two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're creating a clone, there's no need to do a `replaceWith`. Just create new elements with the same content:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xsU7S/1

```
var headingElements = $(':header');

var listElements = headingElements.map(function() {
    return $('<li></li>',{html:this.innerHTML})[0];
});
$('<ul/>').append(listElements).appendTo(".toc");
```

You were replacing each cloned `header` element with an empty `<li>` element. Then you were trying to use the return value from `.each()`, which was actually still a reference to the cloned `header` elements.

Lastly, you were actually appending the `.toc` element to the `listElements` (which again referenced the cloned `header` elements).

Comment: I intended to replace headers with empty li's for the example what has been provided is exactly what I'm looking for (you even put the content in!) however to better understand the issue: I created a cloned set of header elements and then intended to replace those with list items, and place that set into the document. So I don't see why it's bad that each() is still referencing the cloned header elements. I very much like the use of map()... but I'm still confused as to why the original did not work.

Comment: @Quaternion: None of the heading elements referenced in the `headingElements` object were actually being replaced. You were effectively doing `var listElements = headingElements;` where `headingElements` is still the original set. When you did `$(this).replaceWith(...`, you were creating a new jQuery object with `$(this)` that had nothing to do with the original. Since you seemed interested in a new set of `<li>` elements, I used `.map()` which creates a *new* jQuery object filled with whatever you `return` from the function.

Comment: sorry to be such a pain... I didn't know map() existed and that is very valuable I did take the time to understand your solution and am also pleased with learning the jQuery( html, props ) function... this will be useful.  If you have time please take at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6zVa/5/

Comment: @Quaternion: Not a problem. The reason `.text()` works, is that it changes the text content of the `header` item in the set. In other words, it *alters* that element. But the `replaceWith` does *not* alter the element. It exchanges it for a new one. But the exchange is taking place in the new jQuery object you created with `$(this)` instead of the original `headingElements` jQuery object.

Comment: Okay great I understand now, I wanted to get an example working with "replaceWith" so I know why it did not work in the first place and came up with this ugliness http://jsfiddle.net/xsU7S/2/ but it has really helped me understand javascript and jquery better! I wish it was easy to print references in JS so I could see easily that the objects were not the same then I wouldn't have gotten confused.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what your intentions are (which I am not sure that I do) I think you are doing a few things really wrong here.

```
var headingElements = $(':header').clone();
var listElements =  $(headingElements).each(function()
{
    $(this).replaceWith($('<li></li>'));
});
```

Here you are turning each header into an empty `<li>` tag.

```
$(".toc").append('<ul/>').appendTo(listElements);
```

Now you add an empty `<ul>` to `#toc` and then try to add `#toc` to the detached set of empty `<li>` tags.

You should go back to jQuery's documentation and read up on what each of these functions do.